# How do I explicitly instantiate template function?

Tags: c++

So, I have template function, with following structure:

```
class A
{
public: 
    template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
        static constexpr std::array<T, SIZE> B(T min, T max);
    ...
};
```

How do I explicitly instantiate it?
I have already tried following:

```
template std::array<int, std::size_t > B<int, std::size_t>(int min, int max);
template std::array<int, 64> B<int, 64>(int min, int max);
template auto B<int, std::size_t>(int min, int max);
template auto B<int, 64>(int min, int max);
```

As you might guessed, none of them worked

Comment: `template std::array<int, 64> B<int, 64>(int min, int max);` is correct, but depending on where you place it you'll have to qualify `B` as `A::B`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, missed that.